# How add "title" of img and shown with wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, image, wordpress, supersized

I'm scripting a Supersized modded by me, between wordpress and the famous slideshow supersized.

Somewhere,Ii've posted a question (about 7 days ago) about how to insert the images from wordpress to Supersized and resolved. 
My client asked me that he wants the title (into url ) of the image shown at the bottom of homepage.

So I need to insert the titles of the images:

For example:

```
{image : 'http://***.jpg', title : 'title_img'}
```

this modded code is for the image but not title:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            jQuery(function($){
                var imagesArray = [
                <?php 
                function foo($anArray){
                foreach($myimages as $img){
                    echo "\{image : '".$img."'\},";
                }
                }?>
                ];
                $('#container_post img').each(function(){
                    var obj = {};
                    obj.image = this.src ;
                    imagesArray.push(obj);
                });
                $.supersized({

                    // Functionality
                    slideshow               :   1,          // Slideshow on/off
                    autoplay                :   1,          // Slideshow starts playing automatically
                    start_slide             :   1,          // Start slide (0 is random)
                    stop_loop               :   0,          // Pauses slideshow on last slide
                    random                  :   0,          // Randomize slide order (Ignores start slide)
                    slide_interval          :   5000,       // Length between transitions
                    transition              :   6,          // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
                    transition_speed        :   1000,       // Speed of transition
                    new_window              :   1,          // Image links open in new window/tab
                    pause_hover             :   0,          // Pause slideshow on hover
                    keyboard_nav            :   1,          // Keyboard navigation on/off
                    performance             :   1,          // 0-Normal, 1-Hybrid speed/quality, 2-Optimizes image quality, 3-Optimizes transition speed // (Only works for Firefox/IE, not Webkit)
                    image_protect           :   1,          // Disables image dragging and right click with Javascript

                    // Size & Position                         
                    min_width               :   0,          // Min width allowed (in pixels)
                    min_height              :   0,          // Min height allowed (in pixels)
                    vertical_center         :   1,          // Vertically center background
                    horizontal_center       :   1,          // Horizontally center background
                    fit_always              :   0,          // Image will never exceed browser width or height (Ignores min. dimensions)
                    fit_portrait            :   1,          // Portrait images will not exceed browser height
                    fit_landscape           :   0,          // Landscape images will not exceed browser width

                    // Components                           
                    slide_links             :   'blank',    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
                    thumb_links             :   0,          // Individual thumb links for each slide
                    thumbnail_navigation    :   0,          // Thumbnail navigation
                        slides : imagesArray 
, 

                    // Theme Options               
                    progress_bar            :   1,          // Timer for each slide                         
                    mouse_scrub             :   0

                });
            });

        </script>
```

Comment: you can replace title_img with variable etc: <?php echo $image_title ?>.. im not sure how you do but previously im using magicfield to store image files and image title..

Comment: No, it don't work 'cause i've multiple imgs.

Answer (score 0):

i wrote this code about apiField

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var slideTitle = api.getField('title');
        alert(slideTitle);
    });
</script>
```

The browser told me: "undefined"

what is it wrong?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

                jQuery(function($){


                    var imagesArray = [
                    <?php 
                    function foo($anArray){
                    foreach($myimages as $img){
                        echo "\{image : '".$img."', title : '".$img->post_title."'\},";
                    }
                    }?>
                    ];

                    $('#container_post img').each(function(){
                        var obj = {};
                        obj.image = this.src ;
                        imagesArray.push(obj);
                    });
                    var slideTitle = api.getField('title');
                    alert(slideTitle);
                    $.supersized({

                        // Functionality
                        slideshow               :   1,          // Slideshow on/off
                        autoplay                :   1,          // Slideshow starts playing automatically
                        start_slide             :   1,          // Start slide (0 is random)
                        stop_loop               :   0,          // Pauses slideshow on last slide
                        random                  :   0,          // Randomize slide order (Ignores start slide)
                        slide_interval          :   5000,       // Length between transitions
                        transition              :   6,          // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
                        transition_speed        :   1000,       // Speed of transition
                        new_window              :   1,          // Image links open in new window/tab
                        pause_hover             :   0,          // Pause slideshow on hover
                        keyboard_nav            :   1,          // Keyboard navigation on/off
                        performance             :   1,          // 0-Normal, 1-Hybrid speed/quality, 2-Optimizes image quality, 3-Optimizes transition speed // (Only works for Firefox/IE, not Webkit)
                        image_protect           :   1,          // Disables image dragging and right click with Javascript

                        // Size & Position                         
                        min_width               :   0,          // Min width allowed (in pixels)
                        min_height              :   0,          // Min height allowed (in pixels)
                        vertical_center         :   1,          // Vertically center background
                        horizontal_center       :   1,          // Horizontally center background
                        fit_always              :   0,          // Image will never exceed browser width or height (Ignores min. dimensions)
                        fit_portrait            :   1,          // Portrait images will not exceed browser height
                        fit_landscape           :   0,          // Landscape images will not exceed browser width

                        // Components                           
                        slide_links             :   'blank',    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
                        thumb_links             :   0,          // Individual thumb links for each slide
                        thumbnail_navigation    :   0,          // Thumbnail navigation
                            slides : imagesArray 
    , 

                        // Theme Options               
                        progress_bar            :   1,          // Timer for each slide                         
                        mouse_scrub             :   0

                    });
                });

            </script>
```

Comment: i don't know...ah, from query of actual post.